# Unique key on a view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view, key, inline, materialized

I have a view that does not have a unique key (It has a composite key though). I want to create a single numeric key on the fly such that it is consistent across multiple retrievals. ROWNUM is obviously not an option since it can be reassigned when data is inserted/deleted from the view. I do have the option of switching to a materialized view, but not to a lookup based load process (time constraints). 
Is there a way of creating a dynamic unique key in an oracle inline or materialized view that is consistent?

Comment: Can you compute a key?  For example, `rank() over (order by key_col1, key_col2)` will produce a unique, repeated value (assuming `key_col1, key_col2` is unique) as long as the data doesn't change between retrievals.  If the data changes between retrievals, the computed key may or may not still be the same depending on the nature of your data (things like whether rows can be deleted, whether new rows naturally sort after old rows, etc.).

Comment: What do you want to do with this key?  Anything derived from the data in the underlying tables will change every time a record is inserted or deleted, and perhaps updated to.  So what is the point?

Comment: @APC : The purpose is to see if a business key consisting of non-technical columns can be mapped consistently to a unique numerical value. This numerical value can then be used by the consumers of the key as the primary key instead of having to concatenate three different columns.

Answer (score 0):

try 
create or replace someview
as 
select col1||col2 as ukey,col1,col2,col3,col4,etc,etc,etc
from sometable
where whatever

this is where col1 and col2 are the combination key you said you had.